# Leveldb Get last key in key range

Tags: c++, leveldb

In levelDB, key consists of 3 integers concatenated as byte array. For example (using 2 digits for simplicity) 10, 4, 9 will map to key "100409". It's guaranteed that the last digit is sequential starting from 0 and increment by 1, so if "100409" exists that means "100400" to "100408" exists.

I want to find the last key in a specific range given the first 2 numbers, the 3 obvious ways to think of is getting the first key and iterating, but that isn't efficient since the last number is actually 64 bits. Second solution is increment the middle number and go to previous key, but this will cause problems on edge case of last number. Third solution is binary search.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: SeekToLast(partialKey) ?

Comment: SeekToLast doesn't take params

Comment: ah yes, sorry. Weel quick idea would be to store the last 64 bit number in a way that larger numbers are smaller for example f(x) = Int64.MaxValue -  x and then just .Seek